# Initializing a Structure that's within a Structure through a Pointer that points to the first Structure

Tags: c

Basically, I want to make a Pointer to an object from stu_data and then initialize all the variables in it(including the variables of the clg_data structure within). Problem is that I don't know how to access
the second structure with a Pointer.
There's an example of me **trying** to do that below (in void main()).

```
typedef struct {
    int college_id;
    char college_name[50];
} clg_data;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float percentage;
    // structure within structure
    clg_data clg_data;
} stu_data;
stu_data *p;

void main()
{
    stu_data STU1;
    p = &STU1;  
    p->clg_data->college_id = 3; //STU1.clg_data.college_id = 3;  that's basically what I'm trying to achieve here with p.
}
```

Comment: @GIJoe Why not `void main`?

Comment: What, you mean without the "()" ? It wouldn't compile like that

Comment: @MrGuy GI Joe means, why `void` before `main()`

Comment: Well, I didn't know better :P Guess I can do without the "void" part indeed.

Comment: The Standard mandates **ALL** imlpementations to allow `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. It also *allows* other signatures, but these other signatures are not required to be interpreted (or accepted) the same way everywhere. Using `void main()` is unnecessarily locking the program to a specific implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p->clg_data` is not a pointer. Use `.` to access its members

```
    p->clg_data.college_id = 3;
```

Comment: Welp, that was disappointingly easy :P And yeah, that works so tyvm:) Gonna mark that as the answer when I can.

Comment: @rullof: You have to wait a certain time period before you can accept